# Javascript perf, weird results

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to know what is the better way to code in javascript for my nodejs project, so I did this:

```js
function clas(){
}

clas.prototype.index = function(){
 var i = 0;
 while(i < 1000){
  i++;
 }
}

var t1 = new clas();
var f = 0;
var d1 = new Date();
while(f < 1000){
 t1.index();
 f++;
}
console.log("t1: "+(new Date()-d1)+"ms");


f=0;
var d2 = new Date();
while(f < 1000){
 var t2 = new clas();
 t2.index();
 f++;
}
console.log("t2: "+(new Date()-d2)+"ms");
```

on my browser, the first and the second are the same... 1ms and with nodejs, i have t1 = 15ms and t2 = 1ms, why? why the first take more time than the second as he doesn't initialise my class?

Comment: Just a random comment, do you know this site? http://jsperf.com/ this site tests JavaScript for browsers but thought that in most of the cases the winning performance also applies to Node.js.

Comment: Any good JITter will optimize most of the body of `index` out, as it obviously doesn't do anything with `i`. The calls to `index` within the loops should trigger inlining. If the VM is smart enough, it will realize the inlined function is dead code, and could almost elide the entire thing. You need to call some external function from within `index` to prevent that.

Comment: `while(i < 1000){i++;}` is like `i = 1000;` with some compiler optimisations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are several issues. Your example shows that you have very little experience in benchmarking or system performance. That is why I recommend [brushing up on the very basics](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/05/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/), and until you got some more feel for it, don't try optimizing at all. [Optimizing prematurely is generally a bad thing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80094/126027). If done by someone who does not know anything about performance optimization in the first place, "optimizations" end up being pure noise: Some work and some don't, pretty much at random.

For completeness, here are some things that are wrong with your test case:

First of all, `1000` is not enough for a performance test. You want to do iterations in the order of millions for your CPU to actually spend a remarkable amount of time on it.

Secondly, for benchmarking, you want to [use a high performance timer](http://gent.ilcore.com/2012/06/better-timer-for-javascript.html). The reason as to why node gives you 15ms, is because it uses a coarse-grained system timer whose smallest unit is about 15ms, which most probably corresponds to your system's [scheduling granularity](http://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/OperatingSystems/5_CPU_Scheduling.html).

Thirdly, regarding your actual question: Allocating a new object inside your loop, if not necessary, is almost always a bad choice for performance. There is a lot going on under the hood, including the possibility of heap allocations. However, in your simple case, most run-times will probably optimize away most of the overhead, for two reasons:

1. Your test case is too simple, and the optimizer can easily optimize simple code segments, but has a much harder time in real situations.
2. Your test case is [transient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transient_%28computer_programming%29). If the optimizer is smart enough, it will detect that, and it will skip the entire loop.

Comment: Okay ! :D i will try it with more iterations and with a "high performance timer" thanks !

Comment: In the case of node, the high resolution timer would be [`process.hrtime()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime).

Comment: For allocating the new object inside the loop, it was because i wanted to know if, on my nodejs project, create a new controller for every request was bad a bad idea for the perf or if i need to init a controller and let this controller do the work for every request

Answer (score 0):

It is because node does jut-in-time ( JIT )compilation optimizations to the code.

by JIT-optimization, we mean that the node tries to optimize the code when it is executed.

So... the first call the the function is taking more time, and node realizes that it can optimize this for-loop, as it does nothing at all. Whereas for all other calls the optimized loop is executed.

So... subsequent calls will take less time.

You can try by changing the order. The first call will take the more time.

Where as in some browser's the code is optimized ahead-of-time (ie. before running the code).